# python check if multiple substrings are at the start of string words

Tags: python, string, substring, fuzzywuzzy

I'm working with two dataframes, one with abreviations of pharmaceutical forms, and another with the complete version of pharmaceutical forms. I want to check if a string with several substrings (as words) are all contained at the start of a word in another string.

I have:

```
df1
abrev
'dis ijp'
'dis inf'
'dis inj'
```

I'm trying to associate those abreviations to strings with the complete version of those pharmaceutical forms:

```
df2
term
'Dispergovateľná tableta'
'Dispergovateľné tablety do dávkovacieho zariadenia'
'Disperzia na koncentrát na infúznu disperziu'
'Disperzia pre rozprašovač'
```

I tried using `fuzzywuzzy` but it rarely matches with the correct string because I have hundreds of them, so lowering the threshold will result in wrong matches. Most abreviations don't even have the right term in `df2` to match with, as shown in the example.

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
from fuzzywuzzy import process

def fuzzy_partial(df_1, df_2, key1, key2, threshold=90, limit=3):
    """
    :param df_1: the left table to join
    :param df_2: the right table to join
    :param key1: key column of the left table
    :param key2: key column of the right table
    :param threshold: how close the matches should be to return a match, based on Levenshtein distance
    :param limit: the amount of matches that will get returned, these are sorted high to low
    :return: dataframe with boths keys and matches
    """
    s = df_2[key2].tolist()
    
    m = df_1[key1].apply(lambda x: process.extract(x, s, limit=limit, scorer = fuzz.partial_ratio))    
    df_1['matches'] = m
    
    m2 = df_1['matches'].apply(lambda x: '; '.join([i[0] for i in x if i[1] >= threshold]))
    df_1['matches'] = m2
    
    return df_1

fuzzy_partial(df1,df2,'abrev','term',threshold=50)
```

This code sample uses the `partial_ratio` scorer, but I tried with all scorers. That's why I thought of matching the substrings with the start of the words on the complete terms. This way, I would get:

```
df
abrev            term
'dis inf'   'Disperzia na koncentrát na infúznu disperziu'
```

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: can you provide your current code?

Comment: I can't understand what the code is supposed to do. "I'm trying to associate those abreviations to strings with the complete version of those pharmaceutical forms" What does this actually mean? I see three abbreviations, and four longhand versions. Which correspond to which, and according to what rules? I don't see anything like `ijp` or `inj` in the long versions, so how am I supposed to know how it matches up? Also, *what actually is the data*? If these are in Pandas Dataframes, then you should explicitly say so. Otherwise, please clarify.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel edited, most of the long versions don't have abreviations to match with

Comment: Okay, and what kind of correspondences do you expect? How should the results be computed and displayed - do you want to compare every abbreviation to every term, possibly with multiple abbreviations matching the same term, and possibly with multiple terms matching the same abbreviation?

Comment: Ideally the output should be a dataframe with a size equal to the number of abbreviations, and a column with the matches if it has any match. Otherwise return an empty value. Yes i guess multiple abbreviations can match the same term, and vice versa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Concept:**

Look if each word starts with each abbreviation. If yes then count it and compare the next words with the next abbreviation instead. If the final count equals to the number of abbreviation words then it means the term contains all of the abbreviations in them; so, put it in the result list. Do this for all of the terms and abbreviations. Lastly, return the result list to see all of the matched couples.

**Code:**

```
abrevs = ['dis ijp','dis inf','dis inj',]
terms = ['Dispergovateľná tableta',
'Dispergovateľné tablety do dávkovacieho zariadenia',
'Disperzia na koncentrát na infúznu disperziu',
'Disperzia pre rozprašovač',]
def find_all(abrevs, terms):
    result = []
    for abrev in abrevs:
        abrev_match_count = 0
        abrev_split = abrev.split(' ')
        for term in terms:
            for word in term.split(' '):
                if abrev_match_count < len(abrev_split) and word.lower().startswith(abrev_split[abrev_match_count]):
                    abrev_match_count += 1
                    if abrev_match_count == len(abrev_split):
                        result.append((abrev,term))
    return result
print(find_all(abrevs, terms))
```